# How to achieve this destruction effect?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I would like to do something similar at this:
[image]

[youtube: Minecraft Block Destruction with Realistic Physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IHn2uTW8nA&ab_channel=BlockSimulations)

I have two questions:

1. Can I handle a simulation like that or bigger?
   My PC is

```
CPU: i7-7700k 4.20GHz
GPU: 1080ti 11GB
Ram: 32GB ddr4
```

2. How can I set up a simulation like this?
   I know this is a generic question, but even a starting point would be a great answer.

Thank you for your time.

PS: Sorry for my English. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Hi. I've added an image from the video to your question so readers (now and in the future!) can easily see what you are talking about because when the video goes offline, we will have no idea what is this about. Please feel free to add images to your next question. Cheers! (The edit still needs to be approved to be visible.)

Comment: Question 1 is a question of time and hardware. Large simulations will take some time to calculate and bake the simulation. Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QK-MrrO30Og, It's from 2015, render times vary from 1 day to 8 days. Here another one from 2016 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBWijDQ-Nis) render took only a few (4-8) hours.
Question 2: Have a look at Blenderguru's tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHVYYMG3QVY)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*For this purpose blender user usually use Rigid Body simulation. Here is a cookbook for a cube segmented into 10x10x10 (1000 parts). Yes it is process intensive and this is just one cube. The most calculation takes Constraints.*

---

## Create a Cube

- Select a Cube
- Assign Array Modifier > Count=10 > X=1
- Assign Array Modifier > Count=10 > Y=1
- Assign Array Modifier > Count=10 > Z=1

Search for operators:

- Convert to Mesh
- Separate by Loose Parts
- Origin to Geometry
- Move to Collection > New

## Create a floor

Add a Plane and search for operators

- Transform Scale
- Apply Scale

## Create a simulation

With Cubes selected, search for operators:

- Active (Rigid Body)
- Change collision shape > Box
- Connect (Rigid Body)

With Plane selected, search for operators:

- Passive (Rigid Body)
- Change collision shape > Box

[image]

[image]

---

*You can also try version of Blender with Fracture Modifier, that is much comfortable to work with, especially with constraints, but I didnt find grid cuts.*

Comment: You are too kind, this explanation is very good! Thank you very much :)

Comment: You'r welcome :) Also check Creative Schrimp's video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJFE2pb0Ri4 I like result of Molecular add-on, previously I wasn't sure about using cubes, but seems to work very nice and it could be probably much lighter in calculation.