# How to make rigid body constraints more realistic?

Tags: constraints, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I made a cube using 10x10x10 small cubes with rigid body and connected them by rigid body constraints. Cubes and the constraints are all connected to an axis and animated to fall and crash.The constraints are breakable.

[image]

When the cube hit the ground, the cube is broken. (Frame 53) I like this part.

[image]

But after a few frames, some small cubes are going back to the original shape like spring. (frame 90) This is unrealistic.

[image]

The small cubes are supposed to fall apart, I think.
Is there any way to make the rigid body constraints more realistic? I need your help.

Here is my file.
[image]

Comment: You might be interested in the [molecular addon](https://blenderartists.org/t/molecular-for-blender-2-8-2-9/1285205), which uses particles instead of the RB system. I don't suppose setting a more sensitve breakage threshold would be an option, more solver iterations probably won't help, and there don't seem to be any settings for plasticity or the like? Maybe you could keyframe in a second set of constraints that locks the cubes in place on/after impact?

Comment: Related: [How to achieve this destruction effect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/209999/60486)

Answer (score 3):

i am assuming you "just" want to let the cubes fall "realistic" and that they should fall as "one" cube until they touch the ground.

Honestly i don't know whether this works with Rigid body constraint "fixed" and i never tried that. But if you just want that "realistic" physics behaviour as i described in my first sentence - you do not need such a complicated setup at all.

All you need are the cubes, give them rigid body with shape "box" move them up and rotate ... (of course delete all your constraints and all keyframes before) and you will get:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

if you "need" the constraints please improve you question and tell us why you need them and what you expect from them.